# Parsing text from js Map

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am actually new to this so not sure what title should I give. In my node project, I have something like this

```
Map { 'noti:2' => Set {} }
```

I want to access `2` from it. How can I do this?

I tried `Object.keys(obj)` but it doesn't work. Anyone could please explain a little bit what this is called in javascript and how to access 2 from it.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but that seems like invalid syntax.

Comment: Thanks. it's the output of a code `const obj = data.channel.subscriptions
    console.log(obj)`

Comment: Is that _"something like this"_ in your code or is that some console-style output?

Comment: console output.

Comment: See [`Map.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var m = new Map();

m.set('a:1', new Set());

for (let k of m.keys()) {
  let [_, num] = k.split(':');
  console.log(num);
}
```

Comment: The problem is, 1 is not defined, it can be anything like `"noti:2 or noti:242323"` etc

Comment: @sadek why is that a _"problem"_. This code will retrieve the part after `:` in any key in the map

Comment: @sadek ... That's example data.

Comment: Supper. Thank you so much. It works. Yeah, forgot that it was example code :) 

```const obj = data.channel.subscriptions
    for (let k of obj.keys()) {
      let [_, num] = k.split(':');
      console.log(num);
    }```

Thanks again